# How to scale on request with docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have created a puppeteer's bot a put it inside a docker container. Until there, no problem !

But now i need to scale it(by duplicattion) when there is a new request. In fact, if the bot already works on a request, i want an auto scale to a second.

Second question, for you is it better to host it on cloud or a dedicated server ?

I tried to do something with Amazon ECS and fargate but i'm a newbe with thoses technology and i can't do anything which work.

If you have any suggestion,  you're welcome

Thank you a lot for your responses and sorry for my bad English ;)

I want to use a docker application container with auto scale on request. Not a scaling on ressources but on the request.

I tried to do it on Amazon ECS without success. I'm open to other hosting solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run one application container and scale depending on load, take a look at AWS App Runner. It allows you to set a limit on concurrent requests a container can serve, and scale up when that threshold is reached - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/manage-autoscaling.html

Alternatively if it doesn't have to be AWS, this sounds like a use case that would fit the Cloud Run service on Google Cloud.